# How to customise Qt, so it add certain functions in every new cppf file?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am a newbie to Qt, and I was wondering if it was possible to automatically add certain functions declaration in .h file and definition in .cpp file, whenever we add new c++ source file. For ex, if I add new cpp source file(cpp + h file), Qt should add automatically add function initialiseApp(), its declaration in h file and its definition in cpp file. This should also work if I create new project. This makes my work easy as I have to add certain functions in all cpp files. Thanks :)

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion I created. I meant Qt Creator(The Editor)
I just want the editor to add custom functions whenever I add new C++ source file. For Ex, whenever i add new c++ source file it should add a function called initialiseObjects() in header file(its declaration) and in cpp file(just its definition). I know that refractor option exists but i am just too lazy to type the declaration in every new cpp header file and right click on to it to add definition. Once again Sorry for the confusion created

Comment: Post it on Qt development forum.

Comment: @PaulRooney no i just gave an example as initialiseApp, the function i require the most is initialiseObjects(). Even if i inherit the function, i still need to redefine the function, and the code in definition is not the same for all classes.Thanks

Comment: @rakib_ i will surely post. Thanks

Comment: Before posting, you need to understand a bit more what you want and how Qt works and what your C++ compiler is doing. Sounds a lot like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Your question lacks some motivation and is rather off-topic, since too broad. **Why** do you ask? Please **edit your question** to improve and motivate it by adding a few paragraphs.

Comment: I downvoted, because your question is unclear and too broad. I could remove my downvote if you edit your question.

Comment: @GurushantMutteppagol Please add [qt-creator] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your folder:

```
{Path to Qt installation}\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\templates
```

In here you can find all default templates and modify them there.

Comment: Thank you very much, though certain edit is needed here, I'll update the answer :)

Comment: @GurushantMutteppagol Hi if u like my answer then do consider to tick it. Ty fam.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you just want templates to your editor (like [GeneCode answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46557579/841108)) - and then your question is unrelated to Qt as a library and depends much more on your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) - it is not easily possible. Some editors (notably [GNU `emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) are easily customizable with a powerful scripting language (Elisp for `emacs`). Other editors (`vim`, `gedit`) are extensible, notably thru plugins. YMMV.

You could configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool to do additional stuff (it is easy to add a few commands and rules in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)). You could write some scripts or programs to generate initial source code content. You might write your own code preprocessor (or use some additional one, like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)) or write and use some program or script generating C++ code. You could customize your compiler (e.g. developing your own [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)
extensions).

But there is no general way, and your question is too broad, and there are cases where you don't want any automation.

Notice however that in some cases you want some of your C++ code to be generated by something else. That idea is quite common. Qt has [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Qt is a C++ framework. I'd assume you're talking about Qt Creator. In Creator this feature already is there. You can declare a function in `.h` and then right click on it and do **Refactor => Add Definition in MyClass.cpp**.

Comment: I am not sure OP is talking about Qt Creator (then I believe you should not have added that tag in OP's question). You need to ask him

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Using Qt can you _"create a new project?"_ Does it make sense at all?

Comment: Yes of course, I routinely create new projects using Qt (and I use emacs and write my own `Makefile`). I believe that the OP is confused about what Qt is (it is a framework; not an IDE or editor). That is why I downvoted the question (as unclear and too broad). Qt and QtEditor are different projects and tools, an OP did not mention  QtEditor at all and is confused.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes I know. Creating a project is nothing more than creating a couple of files (.cpp or .h) and then putting a makefile beside them. But by _"creating a new project"_ I'd more can think of Qt Creator than creating those files and makefiles. That's why I was adding Qt Creator tag.

Comment: I know this function exists, but i need to manually add the declaration in header file and right click on to it to add definition in cpp file. I just want the qt creator to add the declaration and definition itself. I will try the method suggested by GeneCode.Thanks