# Modify Qt Widgets Application template

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Does anyone know how to customise the template for a Qt Widgets Application?

The examples I have found deal with **"Non-Qt Projects"** specifically the **"Plain C++ Application"**

I would like to create a custom template that includes more files than the default Qt Widgets Application and more #includes and class members.

I can see the files in `.../share/qtcreator/templates/qt4project` and add things to the files already there, e.g. main.cpp but need to add more files there and I dont know where the wizard.json file is to edit.

Is this a built in thing to qtcreator?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557223/how-to-customise-qt-so-it-add-certain-functions-in-every-new-cppf-file/

Comment: Start here: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html

Comment: Not quite a duplicate and I have spent a lot of time searching (including that link) and they all mention modifying the cplusplus wizard which is easy because the wizard.json file is right there. Not so with the Qt Widgets Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, looks like the "Qt Widgets Application" wizard uses hard-coded QWizard pages, not JSON/XML definitions like the simpler ones.

https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt-creator/src/plugins/qmakeprojectmanager/wizards/

`guiappwizard[dialog].*` I think is the one in question, with the base wizard pages/etc from `qtwizard.*`.

So I guess you'd either need to modify the QtC source code, or re-create the app wizard from scratch using your own `wizard.json`. Or perhaps write your own QWizard-based app. But it may be worth examining the QtC `/wizards` code in any case.